# Certain unicode chars are skipped

Tags: unicode

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test⁉
\end{document}
```

Note that the 5th character is "⁉︎" (see http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%E2%81%89%EF%B8%8E&mode=char for info).

The output for this is "Test" without the "⁉︎" part.

I suspect the character ends up being a Mac character rather than a proper UTF-8 char, but I don't know how to fix or check. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is simply there are few fonts that have this character; in particular,`Latin Modern` doesn't have it.

I only know of 4 fonts: DejaVu Sans, DejaVu Serif, Linux BioLinum O and Linux Libertine O. They can be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Linux Libertine O:} \quad Test⁉\smallskip

\texttt{Linux Biolinum: } \quad \fontspec{Linux Biolinum O}Test⁉\smallskip

\sffamily \texttt{DejaVu Sans: }\quad Test⁉

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: EB Garamond, FreeMono, FreeSans, FreeSerif, Junicode, Old Standard (to remain with the freely available font in TeX Live).

Comment: See [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UbAYy.png)

Comment: Yes, I've just checked with another font manager. Good to know that, as it's one of my favourites. I don't have the other fonts installed, so I couldn't check.

Comment: @Kalle, for a list of fonts that support this character, check out [its fileformat.info page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2049/fontsupport.htm).

Comment: Very cool! The text is in Japanese actually, but I know what the problem is now at least so I know where to start hunting. :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell LaTeX that you are using UTF-8 input, and then tell it how to typeset that character (which is not in the standard fonts but can be approximated as follows)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2049}{!\kern-.1em?}
\begin{document}
Test⁉
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh! Thanks a lot! I didn't think about it missing from the font collection.

Comment: @Kalle the default cmr font has 127 characters and Unicode has ~100000 characters so most of them are missing from the font:-)

Comment: That makes sense yeah. :)